# Inserting an image into MySQL database using file upload control

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio

I would like to insert the image into a MySQL database using the file upload control in Visual Studio.  I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and MySQL Community Server with ODBCc and .NET Connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some code that will pull the posted file into a byte array. It'll then pass it down to MySQL. Assumes a `varbinary` column data type. Modify as you need.

```
if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
{
    try
    {
         byte[] img = new byte[FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength- 1];
         img = FileUploadControl.FileBytes;
         InsertImg(img);

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}

....

public void InsertImg(byte[] img) //untested code
{
     using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
     {
         using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
         {
              cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyTable(MyImage) VALUES (@Img)";
              cmd.Parameters.Add("@Img", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary); //or SqlDbType.Image
              cmd.Parameters["@Img"].Value = img;
              conn.Open();
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: getting error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.`

Comment: Try setting type for @Img parameter as System.Data.SqlDbType.Image