# Uploading an image into database in C#

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I created an application in ASP.NET C# and I want to upload an image into MySQL (Binary field) using ASP:FileUpload tool. I could code only the following and couldn't understand the rest. I Googled all the day and couldn't find any relevant. Any help!

**ASPX file**

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

**C# file**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile fup = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
        cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT into profile(picture) VALUES(?)", MyConnection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", OdbcType.Binary) = fup;
        MyConnection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MyConnection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [inserting an image into mysql database using fileupload control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724505/inserting-an-image-into-mysql-database-using-fileupload-control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that these lines are wrong:

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT into profile(picture) VALUES(?)", MyConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", OdbcType.Binary) = fup;
```

I guess this should be like this (or similar - can't test it right now):

```
cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT into profile(picture) VALUES(@picture)", MyConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", OdbcType.Binary).Value = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
```

Also, see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724505/inserting-an-image-into-mysql-database-using-fileupload-control).

Comment: OP also needs to update the OdbcCommand to be something like "INSERT into profile(picture) VALUES(@picture)"

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I hadn't noticed that.